# Python Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, function, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a tough time getting the simplest of Python code running in GCP Functions and would very much appreciate someone pointing out what I might be missing.

My Python is extremely basic and looks like:

main.py

```
import requests

def main():
    """
    Simple
    """

    print("got here ok")
    print("----all good.")

    response = requests.get('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1')
    print(response.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Literally all I want (to start with) is to be able to trigger the function and for it to go off to swapi and bring me  back a chunk of json and to print that out to a log or someplace (just so I can see it did it). Thats all.

I am triggering the function build with a trigger and cloudbuild.yaml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - functions
  - deploy
  - main
  - --source=.
  - --trigger-http
  - --runtime=python38
  - --allow-unauthenticated
```

The git push is putting those files, along with the requirements.txt (which contains the requests package and its transitives) no issue at all. The trigger fires on the push and the function builds ok, as far as I can tell, it results in the little green tick icon.

My expectation is that after the function has built I should be able to trigger it either by hitting the URL google provides or through the test utility in the function control panel.

Whatever I do though, it just results in a 500 server error and no sign from the logs that the function has actually run.

What could I be missing?

Comment: 1) What do the logs for cloud build show? 2) What happens is you deploy directly `gcloud functions deploy`. 3) Cloud Functions do not support `if __name__ == "__main__":`. Functions are not an OS style program so their is no `__main__`. 4) Specify the entry point with `--entry-point=`main`.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems that I immediately see with the main function.

1. it doesn't have any parameters
2. it doesn't return anything

Please try these changes:

1. `def main(request):` as the first line of func `main`
2. `return "success"` as the last line of func `main` (or the response of your choosing).

Please refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips) to see the example. Note the `Ensure HTTP functions send an HTTP response` part as well as the args to contain `request (flask.Request): The request object`.